# how to write case statement in update query in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

how to write below update query in SSIS:

```
 declare @janflag as varchar(56) 
 set @janflag ='y' 
 declare @febflag as varchar(56) 
 set @febflag ='y'/[ SELECT TOP 1 febfl FROM saupdate ]   
      * saupdate table in the control flow.
 UPDATE  sacustomer 
 SET  salesamt1 = CASE WHEN (@janflag='y') THEN ? ELSE salesamt1 END ,
 costamt1 = CASE WHEN (@janflag='y') THEN ? ELSE costamt1 END ,
 qtysold1 = CASE WHEN (@janflag='y') THEN ? ELSE qtysold1 END ,

 salesamt2 = CASE WHEN (@febflag ='y') THEN ? ELSE salesamt1 END ,
 costamt2 = CASE WHEN (@febflag ='y') THEN ? ELSE costamt1 END ,
 qtysold2 = CASE WHEN (@febflag ='y') THEN ? ELSE qtysold1 END 

 where cono=? 
 and yr=?    
 and divno= ? 
 and whse= ?
 and custno= ?
```

Getting error while writing,Please suggest..

Comment: What's the problem? Surely you can just stick that code into the appopriate Task object in an SSIS package? Are you asking which Task to use?

Comment: I am writing the query like:

UPDATE  sacustomer 
SET  salesamt1 = CASE WHEN (@janfl='y') THEN ? ELSE salesamt1 END ,
     salesamt2 = CASE WHEN (@janfl='y') THEN ? ELSE salesamt2 END ,
     salesamt3= CASE WHEN (@janfl='y') THEN ? ELSE salesamt3 END 
 
   WHERE cono = ?
          and yr = ?
          and divno = ?
           and whse = ?
          and custno = ?

Comment: but giving error, I don't know much about SSIS but need to write above query for SSIS..please help.  [ writing in advanced editor to update the records].

Comment: That all looks fine. Are you binding the arguments? I'm sorry I can't help you with that as it's a few months since I did anything with SSIS so I can't remember it exactly and I no longer have access to a system with SSIS installed. It's all described in the documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141134.aspx. Good luck!

Comment: yes binding arguments..so need use ? in update query.but getting error.

Comment: All looks OK to me. It6 might be worthwhile for you to put in the question the query that you're actually using in your Execute SQL Task (?). There's a couple of extra `?`s in the query you put into a comment above - I assume you really have 1 in your `CASE` clauses, as in the question, rather than ? as in the comment. Other than that, I can't see a problem. If you're modifying your question, perhaps you can include the exact error message you're getting as well?

Comment: It would also be helpful if you would post the actual error message that you're getting. You've said three times that you get an error but you've never said what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Possible this be helpful for you -

```
DECLARE @janflag VARCHAR(56) 
SELECT @janflag = 'y' 

UPDATE dbo.sacustomer
SET     
      salesamt1 = 1
    , costamt1 = 1
    , qtysold1 = 1
WHERE cono = '10'
    AND custno = '900'
    AND @janflag = 'y'
```

Comment: Need to update different columns based on flag..and flag is not the part of table (can't use in where).
Need to use case and 1 is not fix. it would be ? that is value from parameter.

Comment: I have 12 flags if janflg is true then update salesamt1,costamt1,qtysold1 columns..if febflg2 then salesamt2,costamt2 and qtysold2..so on.how does it work with all 12 conditions??

Comment: Does repeat the query for each? if yes then how to do mapping ??

Comment: Please provide a full sample of your code. And try to help you.

Comment: I have modified code in my post, also check for Declare parameters, is it write way to declare parameters in SSIS.